# Oracle: create sequence number for repeated rows

Tags: oracle, sequence, repeat

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
ID  VALUE   SEQ

1   100     

2   100     

3   200     

4   200     

5   200
```

Whenever value in column "VALUE is repeated in further rows, value in column "SEQ" must be incremented by 1. Expected output is:

```
ID  VALUE   SEQ

1   100     1

2   100     2

3   200     1

4   200     2

5   200     3
```

As per my understanding it can not be done in insert query while filing data in to this table. It has to be done using post-processing may be. I guess it can be done using analytical function using "row_number() and partition by", but not sure how to do it. Please let me know, if it can be done using some better way. Any hint will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the `SEQ` really have to exist as a permanent row in the table, or is it only useful and relevant when the data is queried? And on a related note, what happens if a row is deleted or updated - do you want a gap/duplicate (you'd get a duplicate if the row with `ID` of `3` had `VALUE` updated to `100`, for example) or the `SEQ` to be recalculated for all the remaining rows?

Comment: the sequence exists permanent in the table. After the rows are deleted or added, modification of sequence is taken care by the triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, value, row_number() over (partition by value order by id) as seq
from your_table;
```