# Oracle: Concatenate sequence number for repeated values

Tags: oracle, sequence, repeat

My situation similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298943/oracle-create-sequence-number-for-repeated-rows) but I just want to create sequence number for repeated values only.

```
Table: MyTable
-----------------------
ID  CODE

1   100     

2   100     

3   200     

4   200     

5   200 

6   300
```

Below is my query:

```
SELECT ID, CODE, (row_number() over (partition by CODE order by ID)) as SEQ from MyTable
```

And this is my current result:

```
ID  CODE    SEQ

1   100     1

2   100     2

3   200     1

4   200     2

5   200     3

6   300     1
```

But my expected result is:

```
ID  CODE    SEQ

1   100     1

2   100     2

3   200     1

4   200     2

5   200     3

6   300
```

Eventually, I do some coding to modify my current result. But I want to ask is there any way to generate the expected result via query only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **CASE COUNT(1) over (partition by CODE)** in your query, see sample query below.

```
WITH MyTable
as (
select 1 id,  100 code from dual union all
select 2 id,  100 code from dual union all
select 3 id,  200 code from dual union all
select 4 id,  200 code from dual union all
select 5 id,  200 code from dual union all
select 6 id,  300 code from dual)
SELECT ID, CODE, CASE COUNT(1) over (partition by CODE)
                    WHEN 1 THEN NULL
                    ELSE row_number() over (partition by CODE order by ID)
                 END as SEQ 
  from MyTable;

        ID       CODE        SEQ
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100          1
         2        100          2
         3        200          1
         4        200          2
         5        200          3
         6        300           

6 rows selected
```